# How to find the best percentage rates of spending per variable to maximize profit for a multi-variable function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a function: d(s*0.68)(c+1)e

Every variable in this function has its own cost to increase.

- d starts at 50 and costs 35 dollars to increase by 1.
- c starts at 0 and costs 40 dollars to increase by 0.01, but has a maximum of 1.
- s starts at 1 and costs 25 dollars to increase by 0.01, but has a maximum of 3.68.
- e starts at 1 and costs 14 dollars to increase by 0.01. But has a maximum of 1.25.

So if I am getting an arbitrary amount of money over time, how much do I spend on each variable to get the highest rate of output? Or more accurately, how can I find the answer?

Comment: Do you have to buy the increases in these increments, or could you spend $4$ dollars to increase $c$ by $0.001$ if you wanted?

Comment: @Ross Millikan The increments are all actually in bundled packages. However, these packages include other variables that aren't a part of the function, so I have to go down another level to narrow down what I need. Using the percentages of spending, I can easily line up the variable increases with various bundles to decide which ones to buy in which order. Or buying different combinations of bundles to reach the required amounts of each variable for the optimal output. To answer your question, just treat the cost like a multiplier of what you want to buy.

Answer (score 1):

For this function, it is convenient to define $c'=c+1$, at which point your function is just $f(d,s,c',e)=0.68dsc'e$  We can use the fact that the log function is monotonic, so maximizing $\log f$ is the same as maximizing $f$ and note that $\log f(d,s,c',e)=\log 0.68 + \log d + \log s+\log c'+\log e$  This shows you are equally interested in proportionate increases in each variable.  Your first money should go into $e$.  Looking at the function, before you raise $e$ you are stuck at zero.  Since the others start at $1$, you should buy $e$ until it hits its maximum.  $d$ is so big already you never want to buy that. You get more bang for your buck buying $s$ than $c'$ until $s=\frac {40}{25}=\frac 85=1.6$, so that will hold you for a while.  Then put equal money into $s$ and $c'$  This ignores the granularity of purchases.  If you have little enough money that the granularity matters you may have to try a number of cases.

Comment: I messed up on a few parts. e actually starts at 1 and has a maximum of 1.25. s has a maximum of 3.68 and c has a maximum of 1. I am very interested to know how you came to your conclusion. Also, are you sure about ignoring d? The rest of the variables are multipliers and d is the number multiplied.

Comment: They are all multiplied together in your formula-there is nothing special about $d$.  If you increase any of $s,e,c'$ from $1$ to $1.01$ you get the same increase in $f$ and the same as if you increase $d$ from $50$ to $50.5$  You get that increase most cheaply by buying $e$.  $d$ is actually next because increasing it by $0.5$ (if you could) would only cost $17.50$